# In angular make $http go to catch if server response with {error:'ok'}

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http.get('/data.json')
.then(function(){console.log('ok'})
.catch(function(){console.log('no ok')})
```

The server response is:

```
200 OK
content-type: application/json

{error:'cannot get the data'}
```

I want that the response will go to the `.catch` not to `.then`.

I know that I can change the response header from the server, but I want to do it only on the client side.

#### In other Words:

How I make angular `$http` promise service, to think that **200 OK** status, with "error" key in the response object, will go to `catch` instead of invoking the `then` function?

Comment: have you tried using 'throw' ?

Comment: Can't you branch in the `then` handler?

Comment: 'catch' is just a shorthand for 'then' function, so promise will never go to 'then' function obviously, and since the promise has been handled it will never go to 'catch'. Also you are missing a response object in then function

Comment: To be slightly pedantic and extend @Indrajith's comment. Catch is shorthand for then(null, function(response) { alert('error caught') }). So it only implements the second argument in the then function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors):

```
yourApp.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', function($q) {
  return {
    response: function(response) {
      if (response.status === 200 && response.data.error) {
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
      else {
        return response;
      }
    }
  };
}]);

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
```

Comment: Thank you. That what I searched for. Most elegant way to not make changes to all the source code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$http.get('/data.json')
.then(function(res){
   if(res.error === 'cannot get the data'){
     return $q.reject(res)
   }
   return res;
)
.then(function(){console.log('ok'})
.catch(function(){
   console.log('no ok')
})
```

Just as others suggested, you can check for the conditions you want the request to be treated as a failure inside the `.then` block and reject using angular `$q` service `reject()` function

Comment: One of your code paths returns a promise, the other doesn't. This is not chainable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev AFAIK return a value inside then() block wraps it up into a promise. but  he can wrap the later part explicitly usng `$q.when()`

Answer (score 1):

As @yarons pointed out, you could use an interceptor. But, your decision was to always return 200, even in an `error` case, so why do you want to change this behaviour in your Front End now?

**Your logic seems like:**

> Don't tell the front end to throw an error (maybe to not show in the
>   dev console or let the user now), but handle it internally as an
>   error.

For me, if you decide to go for this trick-behaviour, go all the way and don't hack something around. Just look in the `then()` for the error message.

So go in the `then()`, as you planned, and then catch your error there with an `if` clause:

```
$http.get('/data.json')
.then(function(response){
    if(response.data.error) {
       $scope.error_message = response.data.error;
       return;
    }
});
```